# What is short-url/address for wordpress.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support

With what short-url can we access this website (rather than typing wordpress.stackexchange.com in address bar) ? Any official short-link there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like Stack Exchange has a shortened URL for most sites. A list of them can be found on this meta answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109802/322985

Ours is: http://s.tk/wp